# Why does my R code give an error when sourcing but not when running the script in itself?

Tags: r

**EDIT:** I have pinpointed the problem. I have a vector of regional codes `regions = df$Code %>% unique`, say `c('A', 'B', 'C')` for the sake of anonymization. When I run `clean_full.R`, this vector indeed contains `c('A', 'B', 'C')`, but when I `source("clean_full.R")`, this vector becomes `c('A', 'B', 'C', NA)`. As such, the code below breaks because it cannot handle `NA`. Currently, I simply put an if-statement to circumvent it but I cannot find out why this `NA` is suddenly appended. Any ideas?

---

I am running a script `model1.R` that sources another script `clean_full.R` in the beginning in order to clean data. When I use `source("clean_full.R")`, I get the error

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

However, if I simply open `clean_full.R` and run this script with `Ctrl+A` & `Ctrl+Enter`, this error does not appear. How can this be and what can I do to solve this?

Here are the first few lines from `model1.R` to show you how I am calling it.

```
source("clean_full.R")
source("config.R")

library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(lmtest)
```

Comment: Hi Mike, please provide the entire contents of `clean_full.R` for the best chance of an answer.

Comment: @Ian Campbell Unfortunately, I cannot share that since the contents of the code are currently confidential. Sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately, it will be very unlikely that anyone could help you without the code that is causing the error.

Comment: Mike, some things to check: (1) if you load `./.Rdata` file interactively, then variables it might have are not available with `Rscript`. (2) On cursory search, that verbatim error comes up in [`Summary.data.frame`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/78283f7c9d3ef7269827aff3e9219273d2a42896/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R#L1703) and nowhere else, look for steps that are summarizing frames; this error suggests you have at least one column that is neither `numeric` nor `complex`. (3) Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/38032814/3358272

Comment: @IanCampbell I understand. I have added an edit that hopefully clarifies and allows an answer without the code.