# Using `any()` over a subset of data.table columns

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to create a new column, "condition_any", in `df` with {data.table} that is TRUE if any of the of the 3 conditions are TRUE, per row.

I tried using `any(.SD)` with no luck:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(id = 1:3,
                 date = Sys.Date() + 1:3,
                 condition1 = c(T, F, F),
                 condition2 = c(T, F, T),
                 condition3 = c(F, F, F))

df[, condition_any := any(.SD), .SDcols = patterns("^condition")]

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work, I thought it would be an easy thing to do.

Thanks

Expected output:

```
   id       date condition1 condition2 condition3 condition_any
1:  1 2021-02-12       TRUE       TRUE      FALSE          TRUE
2:  2 2021-02-13      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE         FALSE
3:  3 2021-02-14      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE          TRUE
```

Comment: This works, but being able to use `any()` would be nice. `df[, condition_any := rowSums(.SD) >= 1, .SDcols = patterns("^condition")]`

Comment: Note: eventually, there will be a helper function `pany` for this: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4448. For now, pseudospin's approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also doesn't use `any` but is a nice way to do it,

```
df[, condition_any := Reduce('|', .SD), .SDcols = patterns("^condition")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code below will give what you want. You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032814/trying-to-understand-r-error-error-in-funxi-only-defined-on-a-data) to see the explanation of the error.

```
df$condition_any <- apply(df[,3:5], 1, function(x) any(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses `any` and works as intended but it would be slow since it is grouping the data rowwise.

```
library(data.table)

df[, condition_any := any(unlist(.SD)), .SDcols = patterns("^condition"),
     1:nrow(df)]
df

#   id       date condition1 condition2 condition3 condition_any
#1:  1 2021-02-12       TRUE       TRUE      FALSE          TRUE
#2:  2 2021-02-13      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE         FALSE
#3:  3 2021-02-14      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE          TRUE
```